# how to access the mysql database in wamp

Tags: mysql, visual-c++, wampserver

I have problem accessing the database from the server which has mysql database using wamp server, And i want to access the database through my **windows pc**, Both server and pc are running on windows 8. please help me with settings 
(Mysql remote access settings)

when i tried to access it give error like 
Can't connect MySql server on '192.168.0.114' (10061)
**MySQL error code 2003**

here 192.168.0.114 is server IP
and i am trying to access using connection string 
`con = driver->connect("tcp://192.168.0.114:3306/", "root", "");` in **VC++**

Comment: What is the error you getting ?

Comment: WAMP has option "Put online" (or sth similar) on notification area icon click. You should check if your firewall does not block the port. You should have database user created - user that have permissions to connect to db from remote machine. Maybe you should also give us the error you get... If it does not work please edit you question and be more precise in writing.

Comment: i have turned off my firewall and antivirus also

Comment: @XaweryWiśniowiecki `Put Online` only effects Apache and not MySQL Server remote access. It is assumed that as the connection to the database will happen in PHP script running on Apache both of which are on the same PC that a connection between PHP and MySQL will only ever be required from localhost. Its also a pretty good security measure to keep MySQL server safe from external hacks.

Comment: @RiggsFolly George haven't said what type of connection he needs... I haven't read nothing about PHP... I'm programming mobile devices and PC (no PHP programming) and I connect to MySQL from other devices without PHP. 

Can't connect MySql server on '192.168.0.114' (10061) - check ports, ping IP, be sure if the server is visible from remote device

Comment: @XaweryWiśniowiecki i have pinged with server , its working . and i have accessed the database directly using browser giving IP address and port it works but coding wise not working.

Comment: but coding wise  it works perfect with localhost

Answer (score 0):

MySQL userid's have a domain associated with them. This controls `from where` the userid can connect from.

If you go to the server and using phpMyAdmin look at your `root` userid's you will see 3 of them.

```
root@127.0.0.1
root@localhost
root@::1
```

The part after the `@` is the domain.

So if you want to connect using the `root` userid from another domain i.e. your PC you will have to add another domain to the `root` userid.

In phpMyAdmin, click the `Users` tab. Go to the bottom and click the `Add User` link.

Create another root userid with a domain of either your specific IP address or if you use just the first 3 quartiles i.e. 192.168.0 you will be able to login from any ip on your local subnet. Of course so will anybody else on that subnet, so make sure you have a `Strong Password` set of `ALL` of the root userids. Also make sure you give this new `root` userid `GLOBAL Privileges`.

A much better idea is to create a totally new userid, leaving the `root` userid available only when you are sitting on the Server running WAMPServer. Give this new userid just the privileges it need on only the one database you are using for this project. Also make sure the new userid can be used from the relevant domains.

Comment: then the error would be "Can't connect with given login password" as I remember exacly. Georgio error looks like the server is not visible outside.

Comment: @XaweryWiśniowiecki server is visible outside coz its pinging

Comment: @XaweryWiśniowiecki Means?

Answer (score 0):

Guys here i found the answer and works fine
but use these configurations on Visual Studio

Download boost.c++Connecter for mysql

PROJECT PROPERTIES:

1.Project_properties->c/c++->General->Additional Include Directories->E:\Project\EcoImpression_OneToN\boost_1_53_0\boost_1_53_0
2.Project_properties->c/c++->Preprocessor->Preprocessor Defination->WIN32;_WINDOWS;NDEBUG
3.Project_properties->linker->General->Additional Library Directories->C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\lib;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 1.1.3\lib
4.Project_properties->linker->input->Additional Dependency->libmysql.lib mysqlcppconn-static.lib mysqlcppconn.lib

TOOLS OPTIONS:

1.VC++ Directories->Inclue Files

C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0\include\win32
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0\include\
E:\Project\VisualConsole\boost_1_53_0\boost_1_53_0

E:\Project\VisualConsole\boost_1_53_0\boost_1_53_0\libs
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 1.1.3\include

2.VC++ Directories->Library Files

C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0\include\win32

E:\Project\EcoImpression_OneToN\boost_1_53_0\boost_1_53_0\libs

DLLs in Windows Folder

copy libmysql.dll and mysqlcppconn.dll to windows folder from MySQL C++ connector

Change Database permissions:

create user 'root'@'192.168.0.118' identified BY 'root';

grant all privileges on *.* to  'root'@'192.168.0.118' with grant option;

create user 'root'@'%' identified BY 'root';

grant all privileges on *.* to  'root'@'%' with grant option;